# #define PARTS_COLUMN "| %-16s | %-50s |\n"

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I saw the following bit of code in a sample **C** file:

`#define TEACHER_TABLE_LINE "| %-16s | %-50s |\n"`

Being really new to **C**, and not being successful with Google, can someone please tell me what this feature is called, so I can look it up properly?

(P.S. Yes, I will take out a good **C** book as soon as possible (recommendations?), but at the moment I need to get this done as quickly as possible.)

Comment: Search terms: macros and C preprocessor

Comment: Please, if you are downvoting, please suggest where I can look for this information in the future so I won't have to ask for easy ones. I honestly couldn't find it anywhere (after almost an hour of looking)

Comment: @lmray - Done Goolge search with "C and #define". **TOP** answer has a very good description. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx

Comment: Then you need to hone your search skills. Googling for "C define" would have brought you to the right place immediately.

Comment: @mat - would have been quicker than typing in a question

Comment: @Mat I did do that, but I couldn't find anything with the `%` sign. I thought it was a special case. Thanks to paxdiablo I now realize that it's intended to be used in a `printf` or something similar.

Comment: I found a good reference of all format parameters, flags etc, at [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a preprocessor macro that defines the preprocessing identifier `TEACHER_TABLE_LINE` so that it gets replaced in the source code with the string `"| %-16s | %-50s |\n"`.

Fron `C11, 6.10.3 Macro replacement /9`:

> A preprocessing directive of the form:
>      `# define identifier replacement-list new-line`
>   defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive.

It basically means that, later on in the code, a statement like:

```
printf (TEACHER_TABLE_LINE, teacherName, teacherAddress);
```

will be treated as if you had written:

```
printf ("| %-16s | %-50s |\n", teacherName, teacherAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will accept in 7 minutes.

Comment: Most likely this will be directly used as a `printf` format, not used in an assignment.

Comment: Good point @alexis, modified to suit.